# PostbackUrl of dynamic GridViews not what I think they should be

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a couple GridViews that are dynamically created and placed into a PlaceHolder. When I mouse over the `Select` button, it shows `__doPostBack('ctl00$bodyPlaceHolder$ctl0X','Select$Y')`, where X = what I think is the GridView/Control index for the page and Y = row number of that GridView.
Since it is dynamically creating the GridViews, it makes sense that names them `ctl0X`, but on the PostBack how do I use this information?
I wouldn't even have this problem if adding the `SelectedIndexChanged` EventHandler worked, but it never gets called.
I found one other question like this, but the answer involved adding a GridView within my GridViews, which would also have to be dynamic, which brings me back to the original problem.



**Edit**
Okay, so I set `gridViewDynamic.ID = "blahblah" + r.LastName`, thus giving each GridView a unique name, so on mouseover in the page I get `__doPostBack('ctl00$bodyPlaceHolder$blahblahSmith',Select$Y`, I still can't access the items on PostBack because they **no longer exist**. So, I added the same GridView creation code to an `if(IsPostBack)`, then called `GridView gView = (GridView)this.Page.FindControl(blahblahSmith)`. Great, `gView` isn't null. But all the data in the rows are. Calling `gView.Rows[0]` returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Page.FindControl("TheNameYouGaveTheDynamicGridView")

```
GridView grid = Page.FindControl("TheNameYouGaveTheDynamicGridView") as GridView;
```

If you are using MasterPages, you need to take a different approach to find the control on the page, but it is the same premise.

Comment: I figured it out. I was not setting the DataKeyNames when I created the GridView. Now in the SelectedIndexChanged EventHandler I can cast the sender as a GridView and use SelectedDataKey.Values to get the values I need. Thanks.  _ _ Though I still feel like the way I'm doing it is kind of dirty. But at least it works.